# Google Feed API Timeout

Tags: javascript, timeout, feed

I've seen it asserted in a few places that the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) has a very short timeout so calls to slow external feeds return with an error relatively quickly.

How short is the timeout?

The [source code](https://www.google.com/uds/api/feeds/1.0/77f89919ef841f93359ce886504e4e3f/default+en.I.js) has no indication I've been able to find. I've tried setting breakpoints on it in a debugger too, but have thus far failed.